# What are the AWS Glue terms Jobs, Job runs and Trigger?

Tags: aws-glue

I am an intern in a IT company and am about to assigned to a AWS Glue related project. I am researching how it works, use cases etc. But these terms keep popping which i couldn't understand properly. I read the definitions and how it seems like more generic. If some one can explain them in simpler manner it would be highly appreciated.

1. Job
2. Job run
3. Trigger

p.s. I still don't have an account to practice these until assign to the project.

Hope somebody will be kind enough to help me!

Comment: The official FAQs explain things very well: https://aws.amazon.com/glue/faqs/
Also the official service documentation has a glossary: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/components-key-concepts.html

Comment: Thank you for the feed back! It was really Helpful!